# Как перенести данные из родительского процесса в дочерний?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++builder, переменные

Есть программа:

```
#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        cout << "Enter first number: ";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Enter second number: ";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "a-b= " << a - b << endl;
        cout << "a+b= " << a + b << endl;
        cout << "a*b= " << a * b << endl;
        cout << "a/b= " << a / b << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Нужно из этой программы перенести переменные в дочерний процесс. Тоесть a и b должны вводиться в консоли родительского процесса, далее создаётся дочерний процесс и все расчёты с ранее введёнными данными производяться в нём.

Comment: Как вариант, использовать [перенаправление ввода-вывода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0), через [стандартные потоки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Comment: Если под linux, используйте fork, он автоматом захватывает контекст. Но, вообще говоря, процессы плохо подходят для передачи данных между ними, нужно использовать либо специальные механизмы межпроцессного  взаимодействия (каналы, очереди сообщений, перенаправление ввода-вывода), либо вообще передавать данные по сетевым протоколам. Быть может, вам нужны всё же потоки (thread), а не процессы?

Comment: @ВикторСмирнов (Windows), нет, нужны именно процессы. Вообще мне примерно обрисовали картину передачи данных с применением `LpCommandLine` в род. процессе и `argv` присвоением в дочернем. Но очень поверхностно, хотелось бы больше информации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример передачи через аргументы командной строки. Если нужна более сложная передача данных, через аргументы командной строки можно передать дескрипторы для более сложных механизмов.

Родительский:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    double a = 0;
    double b = 0;
    cout << "Enter first number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter second number: ";
    cin >> b;
    std::string cl;
    cl += " A " + std::to_string(a);
    cl += " B " + std::to_string(b);

    STARTUPINFO cif;
    ZeroMemory(&cif,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    if (!(CreateProcess("child/child.exe", const_cast<char*>(cl.c_str()),
        NULL,NULL,FALSE,NULL,NULL,NULL,&cif,&pi)==TRUE))
    {
        cout << "Child process not created" << endl;
    }
    cout << "exit_parent" <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Дочерний:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> wrap_command_line(std::size_t argc, char *argv[]){
  std::vector<std::string> ret;
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    ret.emplace_back(argv[i]);
  return ret;
}


std::string getArgument(const std::string& name, const std::vector<std::string>& args){
  auto key = std::find(std::begin(args), std::end(args), name);
  if(key == std::end(args))
    throw std::invalid_argument{("command line argument not found: " + name).c_str()};
  if(++key == std::end(args))
    throw std::invalid_argument{("command line argument is invalid: " + name).c_str()};
  return *key;
}

double getDoubleArg(const std::string& name, const std::vector<std::string>& args){
  return std::stod(getArgument(name, args));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  try{
  std::cout << "child: start" <<std::endl;
  auto args =  wrap_command_line(argc, argv);
  auto a = getDoubleArg("A", args);
  auto b = getDoubleArg("B", args);
  std::cout << "child: a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", a * b = " << a*b <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "exit_child" <<std::endl;
  } catch(const std::exception& e){
     std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() <<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Одним из самых эффективных механизмов межпроцессного взаимодействия является общая память, если вдруг понадобиться, рекомендую Boost.Interprocess http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html